# vb acess create for each range in used range from excel

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I wrote this code but get an error:

```
Function getFileRange(ByVal objFilePath As String) As String
    Dim xlApp As Object
    Dim xlWb As Object
    Dim xlSheet As Object
    Dim rng As Object
    Dim usedRng As Variant

    Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    Set xlfile = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(objFilePath)
    Set xlSheet = xlfile.Sheets(1)

    usedRng = xlSheet.usedRange.Address
    getFileRange = Replace(usedRng, "$", "")

    For Each rng In usedRng
        If rng.MergeCells Then
            With rng.MergeArea
                .UnMerge
                .Formula = rng.Formula
            End With
        End If
    Next


    Debug.Print getFileRange

    Workbooks.Close True

    Set xlApp = Nothing
    Set xlfile = Nothing
    Set xlSheet = Nothing

End Function
```

how to define rng as range in excel? Any reference where I can learn about converting excel vb in vb access? (I don't know how you say it, I need to know a lot about creating excel application in access vice versa)

Comment: `Dim rng as Range`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You define it as `Dim rng as Range`.
And then you should set it. The same for usedRng. The property `Address` of the range is a `String`, you should **not** refer to it. In general, in your code it looks like this:

```
Dim rng       As Range
Dim usedRng   As Range
set usedRng = xlSheet.usedRange
```

Then it could work.

---

You may also use Late Binding, if you miss the `Microsoft Excel N Object Library`. Then something like this could do the job:

```
Dim rng     As Object
Dim usedRng As Object

Set usedRng = xlSheet.usedRange
```

Comment: It won't recognize the as Range error: user-defined type not defined. Do I miss any reference?

Comment: @Anthony - give a screenshot of the references. You should have `Microsoft Excel N Object Library`

Comment: yup i missed that library. Already added and works. but I got different error now on usedRng = xlSheet.usedRange.Address "object variable or with block variable not set."

Comment: @Anthony - why are you using `.Address`??? - check my answer above.

Comment: could you edit your answer? put the missing library so I can mark as answer.

Comment: @Anthony - the missing library is there.

Comment: I didn't use the .address before, it didn't return the address when I didn't use the .address. however I have removed it now and the error is "for each may only iterate over a collection object or an array"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150584/discussion-between-vityata-and-anthony).

Comment: @Anthony - `Dim rng as Variant`, if you cannot define it as a range.

Comment: do you have any reference for me to read about this (using excel code in access)? not sure the keyword to google  a bit hard since it's not my native language.

Comment: @Anthony http://spreadsheetpage.com/index.php/tip/referring_to_ranges_in_your_vba_code/ and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-object-excel

Comment: thank you for your best support!

Comment: @Anthony - welcome :)